# "Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code" Visual Studio Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, monogame, opentk

I am getting the above error when I try to run my project, along with

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in OpenTK.dll Additional information: Index was outside the
>   bounds of the array.

I am getting this by trying to run the project in both VS2017 and 2019.

This is an older MonoGame project that I started working on again after a long hiatus, and I've had no trouble working on it until now.

I even tried to open up the quite old copy I had of the project, and now I get this same error when trying to run even that, so I'm sure it's nothing I did code wise between now and when it worked last night.

I've been looking through posts on here for a few hours now and so far nothing has worked. I was about ready to try copying everything into a new project in case something with the solution got messed up, but since not even the old version is working... I don't know. Any more ideas would be appreciated.

The XML Configuration of the two OpenTK.dll files in my project folder, (only one I've been able to open and look at):

```
    <configuration>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="opengl32.dll" target="libGL.so.1"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="glu32.dll" target="libGLU.so.1"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="openal32.dll" target="libopenal.so.1"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="alut.dll" target="libalut.so.0"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="opencl.dll" target="libOpenCL.so"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="libX11" target="libX11.so.6"/>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="libXi" target="libXi.so.6"/>
  <dllmap os="osx" dll="openal32.dll" target="/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/OpenAL" />
  <dllmap os="osx" dll="alut.dll" target="/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/OpenAL" />
  <dllmap os="osx" dll="libGLES.dll" target="/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES" />
  <dllmap os="osx" dll="libGLESv2.dll" target="/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES" />
  <dllmap os="osx" dll="opencl.dll" target="/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL"/>
</configuration>
```

[files list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrnrh.png)

Comment: Hey there mind Posting the OpenTK.dll if you can and we'll show you, I'm 90% sure what the issue is but just want to be a 100%

Comment: I have two OpenTK.dll files in the project folder, one (application extension type) that I can't find anything to open to see the contents, which I have tried uploading here https://gofile.io/?c=OTKZLW , and the other type xml configuration which I can see in VS and will add the original post in a moment.

Answer (score -1):

I had a look threw the Provided file's and I doubt your errors happening there. So The error is pretty clear about what's happening so because I dont have all your code what i'm going to suggest is Go threw the application code bases and Breakpoint every

- Array
- Array Call

What does the error mean?
This exception means that you're trying to access a collection item by index, using an invalid index. An index is invalid when it's lower than the collection's lower bound or greater than or equal to the number of elements it contains.

So in Short if you have a Array X

```
string[] x = new string[4];
```

And you call that array with a Index of `x[5]`, Your asking for something outside of the scope of that array(It's trying to retrieve Data that **Cannot Exists** in this context)

Comment: Doubtful it was anything like that. Didn't change anything array related between it working and it not, now would that explain a very old copy of the project, that worked when I made it (a backup of a working version) suddenly not working. In the mean time, since posting this, I made a new project in the newest version of monogame (which doesn't use those OpenTK files anymore I noticed), and 'remade' the project by creating fresh files and copy-pasting over all the code, in the state that wasn't working. This fresh version in the new monogame VS project is working just fine (luckily).

Comment: So yea, I don't know what it could have been then. Thanks for taking a look though. Would have been nice to get the old one back to not loose my images that I only have the no unusable xnb files for, so there would still be value in getting the old one working. At least I'm not at a total loss... Still curious though.

Comment: It's weird because that error is Literally a index out of range, But as you say a Update fixed it, So maybe there was something wrong the Version of Mono Game's and another Nuget of yours that Conflicted? Maybe something that wrote to the OpenTK?   As you say The error is possibly in the OpenTK but from what I saw there was nothing to Indicate such. So maybe on the Compile something wrote to the OpenTK that was causing it to call something out of range.

Comment: Hmm maybe. This isn't the original version of VS I started the project in, but then unless something else updated that I didn't notice, it's not like it didn't work in this VS version before. My computer doesn't think the TK files have been modified recently, accounting to the last modified date, so I'm now doubting they got messed up. Unless there's something else tied to them I'm not aware of. Eh, think this one may just wind up staying a mystery. Just glad the new monogame doesn't seem to use the OpenTK stuff at all hopefully won't have to worry about triggering it again.

Comment: Its honestly a bit of a stray for me, I wish I could be more help but yeah I think this one will just remain a "Vs moment" But as you say the MonoGame's update Circumvents the issue so doubt you'll face it again at-least in this context